# Azure VM Join Azure AD Domain - User Locked Out

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am attempting to join my Azure vm to my newly created Azure AD Domain. Once I have entered my desired domain and select ok, then I am asked to provide credentials. My credentials are consistently revoked stating my user is 'locked out'. My user is a AAD DC Administrator, and I have tried resetting my password, but I continue to get this error. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Have you added your user account into the local admin group in the VM? I tried on my side, I could use an AAD DC Admin account to login VM.

Comment: Did you find a solution?